# Is it possible to call the DESCRIPTION value of type IFC in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge, ifc

[image]

I am working on an IFC file using Forge Viewer.

As shown in the figure above, if you check the property information in Forge Viewer, you can check the DESCRIPTION value.
I want to know if an API that can call the DESCRIPTION value is provided.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [PropertiesManagerExtension.](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/PropertiesManagerExtension/)

Example implementation is given in [this blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/adding-custom-properties-property-panel)